# Multiplot in Gnuplot via Python

Tags: python, gnuplot

I'd like to get three charts, one under one, using `multiplot`.

I tried:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
from numpy import *
import Gnuplot as gp
import Gnuplot.funcutils

x = (1,2,3)
y=(2,4,5)
x1 = (3,6,8)
g = gp.Gnuplot()
g("set output 'filename.svg'")
g("unset xtics")
g("unset ytics")
g("set size 200,200")
g("set bmargin 0")
g("set tmargin 0")
g("set lmargin 0")
g("set rmargin 0")

g("set multiplot")
#First
g("set origin 0.1,0.1")
d = gp.Data(x,y,with_="linespoints")
g.plot(d)
#Second
g("set origin 0.1,50")
d1 = gp.Data(x1,y,with_="linespoints")
g.plot(d1)
# Third
g("set origin 0.1,100")
d2 = gp.Data(y,x,with_="linespoints")
g.plot(d2)
g("unset multiplot")
```

starting from [http://t16web.lanl.gov/Kawano/gnuplot/plot3-e.html](http://web.archive.org/web/20100906164423/http://t16web.lanl.gov/Kawano/gnuplot/plot3-e.html)

But I get an error when I wanna display the svg created. 
Suggestions?
FB

Comment: What is the error you get? You may want to update your question with this information.

Comment: Is there a data file that goes with this?

Comment: @Levon the datafile is generated by gnuplot-py from the iterables `x`,`y`, and `x1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you aren't setting the terminal.  Gnuplot's just sending the output to the x11 terminal (or whatever you've configured to be default).  if your default terminal isn't `svg`, then you'll get an error -- either the file won't exist, of the type of encoding won't match the `svg` extension.

add `g("set terminal svg")` right before `g("set output 'filename.svg'")` and you should be all set.

Comment: I got the image, but it's wrong. I get just the first plot and it's not "complete" (I don't see the whole white window)

Comment: @FrankBr : That's probably because you're using `set size 200,200` which I advised you remove before ;).  You (probably) want to remove that line and do `g("set terminal svg size 200,200")`.

Comment: Also, your `g("set origin 0.1,100")` should be `g("set origin 0.1,1")`  (1 instead of 100. the range is [0-1]). But you probably don't even want that since that will put the left edge of your plot on the right edge of the "canvas"

Comment: I modified like you adviced me and now I got something that sound "more correct" than before. I see just two parts of the expected fig, but there are no "complete".

Comment: @FrankBr : This layout is usually easier to achieve using `g("set multiplot layout 3,1")` (and commenting out the `set origin` commands)

Comment: It works!! Thank you so much!! Just another question: if I wanted add some space between plots. how would I get this?

Comment: @FrankBr : There is usually space between the plots, it is absent because you have the `g('set margin 0')` series of commands.  Remove them and you should get some space between.  Also, if this works for you, feel free to accept it as an answer to give some closure ( http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work )

Comment: I miss just the transparency and then it's all perfect. 
Anyway, I'll mark it.